# Error Crawl to the Google next page using Watin

Tags: c#, watin

I want to crawl to the Google next page using Watin but it has some errors
Here is my code:

```
               string[] page = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < NumOfPage; i++)
                {
                    page[i] = ('"' + i + '"').ToString();
                }
               int count=1;
               while (count<NumOfPage)
                {
                     ie.Link(Find.ByText(page[count])).Click();                                                                                


                    }

                    count++;
                }
```

But it has an error**"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** at line `page[i] = ('"' + i + '"').ToString();` I wonder that if it has some errors when casting int to string???

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're performing *integer* arithmetic. I suspect you want:

```
page[i] = "\"" + i + "\"";
```

Then you'll be performing string concatenation, which is surely what you want.

EDIT: If you don't actually need the quotes, it's even simpler:

```
page[i] = i.ToString();
```

Currently you're getting the exception because `Find.ByText` is presumably returning null, as it's not finding the link.

On the other hand, I have to say - if you're programmatically crawling Google, have you checked the [terms of service](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/) first?

Comment: I have a simple code:
`ie.Link(Find.ByText("1")).Click();`, I think the element in `ByText($$$)` should be `ByText("a number")`, not ` "\"" + i + "\""`

Comment: @vyclarks: You mean you just want the number? You don't want any quotes? You need to be very clear about the *actual content* you want in `page[i]`.

Comment: Cause I have a simple code for specifical page is:  `ie.Link(Find.ByText("1")).Click(); `, and now I make a loop for a range page, But when making a loop I have a problem in using a variable "i"

Comment: @vyclarks: It's not clear what you mean by "I have a problem in using a variable i". And again, you should check the Google terms and conditions to check whether what you're doing complies with them.

Comment: Sorry if I can make you understand what I want. Dear, all I want is make a loop to go to the next Google page, next and next... But I can't make it work.

Comment: @vyclarks: Well I've explained what you need to do in order to get an array of "1", "2" etc. If that's not working, you'll need to give more details. "I can't make it work" isn't *nearly* enough information.

Comment: Thank you guy, I've got an array of "1","2" by your way. Thanks a lot, But it  still doesn't work, I mean it still cannot go to the next page even I think that code is right. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Can you help me???

Comment: @vyclarks: No. You need to perform a *lot* more diagnostic work, to find out which exact part of it isn't working (e.g. Find.ByText, or Link etc). Then I suggest you create a new question with all the appropriate information. And again, I urge you to look at the terms and conditions.

Comment: Hope it's clear enough [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502949/error-when-making-a-loop-to-crawl-google-next-page-watin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502949/error-when-making-a-loop-to-crawl-google-next-page-watin)

Answer (score 0):

at line 
string[] page = null;
you set the page variable to null and you should initialize it .
you can change your code like it

```
            string[] page = string[1];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumOfPage; i++)
            {
                Array.Resize<string> (ref page, i+1);
                page[i] = "\"" + i.ToString() + "\"";
            }
           int count=1;
           while (count<NumOfPage)
            {
                 ie.Link(Find.ByText(page[count])).Click();                                                                                


                }

                count++;
            }
```

i first set page array to 1 and then before calling to set the value for each array resize it . 
aslo i cahnged another line that i think it would generate error.

Comment: Invalid expression term 'string' -> error for this line: `string[] page = string[1];`