# Error When making a loop to crawl Google next page Watin

Tags: c#, watin

I have a simple code that help me crawl to page 2 of Google result page:

```
var ie= new IE();
ie.Link(Find.ByText("2")).Click();
```

All I want is crawling to more next page with the inputed number of page, so that I make a loop like this:

```
                string[] page = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < NumOfPage; i++)
                {
                 Array.Resize<string> (ref page, i+1);
                page[i] = "\"" + i.ToString() + "\"";
                }
               int count=2;
               while (count<NumOfPage)
                {
                     ie.Link(Find.ByText(page[count])).Click();                                                                                
                     count++;    
                }
```

But the result is it pause at the first page, no crawling to the next page. It's seem the loop doesn't work. Where is the problem???

Comment: Nope, you still haven't really provided enough information. What happens when you debug through the code, step by step, for example? What is `NumOfPage`? (And why are you using an array at all, and why are you using a `while` loop when a `for` loop would be simpler?)

Comment: NumOfPage is a number of page that I want to surf, for example: 10. Num Of Page is inputed in a textbox. While or For is not a problem men, as long as the syntax is right. I've debuged already, the page[i]="i" as I want. So everthing seem right, that is the reason I dont know why it doesn't work guy

Comment: Well you haven't said anything about what happens when you step through within your loop. I would also recommend that you separate `ie.Link(Find.ByText(page[count])).Click()` into three steps: the call to `Find.ByText`, the call to `Link`, and the call to `Click`. That'll make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use `Click()` method to go to the next page, I recognized that `Click()` will be performed only when the `Link` is visible, so you have to scroll the vertical scrollbar to the bottom to show the `Link` first (scrolling manually or programmatically works as you want). However I think to go to the next page, you can call the method `GoTo()` instead with the `Url` got from the found `Link`. I've tested it OK but the delay between page switches is a little large (about 2 seconds or above). I don't know why you want to do this and would like to know it from you:

```
for (int i = 2; i < NumOfPage; i++)
{
   ie.GoTo(ie.Link(WatiN.Core.Find.ByText(i.ToString())).Url);//Don't need quotes at all.
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
       // Setup browser object
        var browser = new IE();
        var url = "www.google.com";
        browser.GoTo(url);

        var searchBox = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q"));
        searchBox.Value="Rex";

        //click on the search button
        var btnSearch = browser.Button(Find.ByValue("Search"));
        btnSearch.Click();
        //wait for browser to load properly
        browser.WaitForComplete();

        // Find the navigation menu table            
        var navigationtable = browser.Table(Find.ById("nav"));

        // To go to the second page
        var secondpage = navigationtable.Link(Find.ByText("2"));
        secondpage.Click();
        //wait for browser to load properly
        browser.WaitForComplete();
```

this simply goes to the second page
now if you want to loop through

then

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
{
var nextpage = navigationtable.Link(Find.ByText("i"));
//check if the link exists
/if yes then click on it
if(nextpage.Exists)
nextpage.click();
browser.waitforComplete
}
```